# How to Upload Image in AWS s3 , getting error at upload time

Tags: objective-c, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am Using latest SDK library of amazon for upload image to bucket. but getting error, here is my code

App Delegate code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:AWSRegionAPSoutheast1
                                                                                                identityPoolId:AWS_IDENTITY_POOL_ID1];
    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionAPSoutheast1
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;

    return YES;
}
```

My View Controller Code is

```
    AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];
    NSString *downloadingFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloaded-myImage.jpg"];
    NSURL *downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:downloadingFilePath];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:downloadingFilePath];

    AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *uploadRequest = [AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest new];
    uploadRequest.bucket = @"myBucketName";
    uploadRequest.key = @"downloaded-myImage.jpg";
    uploadRequest.body = downloadingFileURL;

    [[transferManager upload:uploadRequest] continueWithExecutor:[AWSExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                   withBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
                                                       if (task.error) {
                                                           if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                               switch (task.error.code) {
                                                                   case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                   case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                       break;

                                                                   default:
                                                                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                       break;
                                                               }
                                                           } else {
                                                               // Unknown error.
                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                           }
                                                       }

                                                       if (task.result) {
                                                           AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
                                                           // The file uploaded successfully.
                                                           NSLog(@"LOG %@", task.result);
                                                       }
                                                       return nil;
                                                   }];

   [transferManager upload:uploadRequest];
```

But Every time getting error like this

```
 AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:528 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke352 | Unable to refresh. 
 Error is [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." 
 UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffd7300a070 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" 
 UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://cognito-identity.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/, 
 NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cognito-identity.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, 
 NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}]
```

Comment: How are you authenticating? you provide temporary access through Cognito?

Comment: @Tom  i just Edit my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Cognito Identity currently is only available in us-east-1, eu-west-1, and ap-northeast-1. When instantiating the AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider you will need to use the region that your Cognito Identity Pool was created in.

You can still use the credentials obtained by Cognito Identity for other services in other regions.

Answer (score 1):

The supported endpoints for Cognito Identity are (taken from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cognito_identity_region):

```
Region Name             Region         Endpoint                                      Protocol
US East (N. Virginia)   us-east-1      cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com      HTTPS
EU (Ireland)            eu-west-1      cognito-identity.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com      HTTPS
Asia Pacific (Tokyo)    ap-northeast-1 cognito-identity.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com HTTPS
```

It looks like Cognito Identity is not supported in the Singapore region (ap-southeast-1).  Try a different region from the list above.